# Closure use of non-escaping parameter in TaskQueue

Tags: ios, closures, swift3, task-queue

i have a problem with the next code:

```
func +=! (tasks: inout [TaskQueue.ClosureWithResultNext], task: @escaping TaskQueue.ClosureWithResultNext) {
tasks += [{
    result, next in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        task(result, next)
    })
}] }



func +=! (tasks:inout [TaskQueue.ClosureWithResultNext], task: @escaping TaskQueue.ClosureNoResultNext) {
tasks += [{
    _, next in
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        task()
        next(nil)
    }
}]}
```

And i get problem with next with  non-escaping parameter, if somebody could help me please with these problem.

> Full error message is Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'next' may
>   allow it to escape.

Thanks.

Comment: Compiles fine for me with the latest version of TaskQueue – on what line do you get the error, and what's the full error message?

Comment: Full error message is  Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'next' may allow it to escape.